# Failed to create symbolic link, what should I do?

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link

When I enter the following command on a terminal session.

```
$ sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver /usr/bin/utserver
```

It shows me the following message

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/utserver’: File exists
```

`sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver /usr/bin/utserver` failed to create the symbolic link.

What should I do?

Comment: You mean `ln -s`?

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? What is `"$i"`?

Comment: i didn't mean that sorry

Comment: it's duplicated.

Comment: You could also just use the `-f` option of `ln` to force overwriting existing files: `sudo ln -sf /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver /usr/bin/utserver`

Answer (score 22):

You should check if the symbolic link /usr/bin/utserver exists. If it does, you could unlink it:

```
sudo unlink /usr/bin/utserver
```

then redo the ln command

```
sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver /usr/bin/utserver
```

Cheers,

Comment: it say cannot unlink permission denied

Comment: Use `sudo unlink /usr/bin/utserver`

Comment: no such file or directory

Comment: Could you use `ls -l /usr/bin | grep utserver` and give the output?

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          40 Dec  1 17:11 utserver -> /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/utserver
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          36 Dec  1 17:15 utservercd -> /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/utservercd

Comment: so apparently `/usr/bin/utserver` is pointing to the correct target `/opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/utserver`. Your symbolic link creation worked.

Comment: utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/
bash: /usr/bin/utserver: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: That means your symbolic link works but your download of utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3 might be corrupted. Try to re-download it.

Comment: i have done still doesn't work,will you help me with the remote thing

Comment: I suppose you have the 64bit version which is not compatible with your 32bit kernel. You should download the 32bit version instead.

Comment: You are welcome. Please up vote our answers too.

Comment: It removed my original file :-(

Comment: Sorry I do not get your point. You tried to unlink the existing symbolic link and it was removed?

Answer (score 0):

### **$ man ln**

```
ln [OPTION]... TARGET
```

This creates a link to TARGET in the current directory.

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/utserver
cd /usr/bin/     
sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver
```

Make sure the file `/opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver` exists. If not use a valid path.

**-- UPDATE**

Given the information:
The link `/usr/bin/utserver` points to the correct target `/opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver`

So the symbolic link is already set. Any other errors you may have is nothing to do with `ln` part.

By the given `uname -a` you're using 32 bit OS. So you should [download and install](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/install-utorrent-ubuntu-14-10/) the **32 bit** version of µTorrent Server.

Comment: that won't work either

Comment: @mollllll Output of `ls /opt `

Comment: what do i write then?

Comment: Paste the output of `ls /opt /usr/bin` [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and give me the url.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13601621/

Comment: Output of `ls -l /usr/bin/utserver`

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 Dec  1 17:11 /usr/bin/utserver -> /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/utserver

Comment: Output of `ls /opt`

Comment: utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3  utorrent-server-v3_0

Comment: @mollllll `uname -a`

Comment: Linux best-W760T-M740T-M760T 3.13.0-55-generic #94-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 18 00:28:41 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: @mollllll Please see the updated answer

Comment: @mollllll  Please let us know what actually fixed your problem. And you can mark an answer as accepted ; )

Comment: okay it was deleting the file and then downloading the 32bit file,thankyou

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to help, the target already exists. You could remove the target and after that create the symbolic link again:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/utserver
sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver /usr/bin/utserver
```